# error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required during installation of pandas-profiling

Tags: python, c++, pandas

As a dependency of the Python module pandas-profiling, an attempt is made to install the module Bottleneck (offers Fast NumPy array functions - but is written in C).
The installation aborts with this error message:

```
   error: Microsoft Visual C ++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C ++ Build Tools": https: // visualstudio
.microsoft.com / visual-cpp-build-tools /
   ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Failed building wheel for bottleneck
Failed to build bottleneck
```

The proposed solution would mean downloading and installing the "Microsoft C ++ Build Tools" from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/.
However, that would only consume> 6GB hard drive space because I don't use Visual Studio.

Do any of you have an idea for a different solution?

Comment: Maybe it supports some version of mingw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a compiled version of the module Bottleneck ([Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#bottleneck).
After the installation as wheel the Python module pandas-profiling could be updated.